# ActionScript 3 textfield disable default cursor

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking for a way in ActionScript 3 to allow the user to scroll a TextField (left to right) if the amount of text is greater than the TextField's width without the cursor changing to the flashing I.

The textfield is inside a MovieClip. I cannot use MouseChildren = false and selectable = false as both stop the textfield being scrollable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the simplest way is to set the myTextField.selectable = false. The cursor doesn't change and the text field's content remains scrollable. Maybe I missed something here, but it works on my simple test.

Comment: I created a small project from scratch and cannot replicate this result as the TextField is now un-scrollable. I'm honestly unsure how you've managed to do that. Maybe you can provide an example of this working?

Comment: Sure, you can find the example [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/0rVK). Since the page there has its own scrollable content, it would be better to switch the preview into full-screen mode.

Comment: I think I may have worded my question poorly. The TextField needs to be scrollable not draggable. I have TextField which contains text that is too long for the textfield so this is hidden. I want the user to be able to scroll the TextField from left to right to be able to view all the text. The issue I have is that if I the TextField is selectable the textfield cannot be scrolled from left to right.

Comment: I've edited my question to better reflect what I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: @AntBirch : in this case, you can try the approach suggested by www0z0k. A  ***very*** basic example you can find [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/c6tl)

Comment: i've marked this as the correct answer as it worked best for me. My only change was to instead of using just deltaX I wrapped this with Math.round() which keeps the jumping around caused at the start of the TextField to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:
switch off mouse interactivity for the child `TextField`

```
mc.mouseChildren = false;
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, scroll);
```

and scroll it manually:

```
private function scroll(e:MouseEvent):void{
    tf.scrollV += e.delta;           
}
```

Working example [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/yrHY)

**update:**
To scroll text horizontally you need to change the [scrollH](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollH) property of the `TextField`, for example you may handle `MOUSE_WHEEL` event like this:

```
private function scroll(e:MouseEvent):void{
    tf.scrollH -= e.delta;           
}
```

Comment: I think there's a little confusion with this answer. I don't want to be able to drag the MovieClip around at all I just want the text to be scrollable as it normally would with a dynamic TextField.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still open to suggestions...
 
(This is roll-over scrolling instead of mouse-down to scroll by dragging)

```
var scrollSize : int = 5; //# scrolling speed
tf.selectable = false;
tf.height = 25; //# (set height only if [tf] is already on Stage with text)

tf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, scroll_start);
tf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, scroll_stop);

function scroll_start (evt:MouseEvent) : void
{ tf.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handler_enterFrame ); }

function scroll_stop (evt:MouseEvent) : void
{ tf.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handler_enterFrame ); }

function handler_enterFrame (evt:Event) : void
{
    //# touch right edge = scroll text towards left
    if ( tf.mouseX >= (tf.width - 10) ) {  tf.scrollH += scrollSize; }

    //# touch left edge = scroll text towards right
    if ( tf.mouseX <= (tf.x + 10) ) 
    { 
        if ( tf.scrollH > 0 ){ tf.scrollH -= scrollSize; }
        else { /* do else here = Hurray */ }
    }
}
```

There is a weird effect that **only** happens if you scroll fully to the end of text/sentence and then immediately scroll backwards, when it reaches zero scroll there is a "bounce" effect. Likely caused by **Enter Frame** event. Will check that later tonight if possible but the general concept is there in code...

Gotta fly but hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately MOUSE_OVER isn't the right for this project but will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @AntBirch, no worries pal, you have a working solution now.